Gradients do not exist (keras-tcn)
If I execute the code at the buttom I get the following warning:
Gradients do not exist for variables ['kernel', 'bias'] when minimizing the loss. If using model.compile(), did you forget to provide a loss argument?
Does this error occurs in your environment, too? And do you know what could be the reason for this warning?
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling1D, Dense, Input
from keras.models import Sequential 
import keras
from tcn import TCN
import numpy as np
import warnings
import sys

warnings.filterwarnings("error") # Convert warnings to exceptions
try:
    # Your code here
    Modell = Sequential()
    # TCN
    Modell.add(Input(shape=(None, 4)))
    Modell.add( TCN(nb_filters=2, kernel_size=91, nb_stacks=1, dilations=[1], padding='causal', 
                    use_skip_connections=True, dropout_rate=0.0, return_sequences=True, activation='relu') )
    Modell.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())   
    # DENSE
    Modell.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    Modell.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    Modell.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
    Modell.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.006712461356073618), loss='SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
    batch = np.array([[-1.1,  0.5 , 0.9 , 0.02],
            [-1.0024, -0.18,  0.9, 0.02],
            [-1.0027, -0.52,  0.9, 0.02]])
    labels_batch = 1
    history = Modell.fit(np.array([batch]), np.array([labels_batch]), epochs=1, verbose=0)
except Warning as e:
    print(f"Warning encountered: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)  # Exit the program with a status code

Versions:
tf: 2.16.1
keras: 3.4.1
keras-tcn: 3.5.0

This question is similar to: Warning: Gradients do not exist for variables. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please make sure to include a language tag when relevant. In this case, this question should probably be tagged with [tag:python].
